# How can I use a dynamically generated path in JS to generate a URL for my <img>'s src attribute in my view.blade.php?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In my `$.ajax()` from my JQuery script written inline in my `blade.php` view file, I have received a path to an image file (relative to public folder, like `/thumbnails/87991.png`) as a response. Say the response in `success()` of `$.ajax()` is stored in variable `dataReturned`.

```
console.log('dataReturned:'+dataReturned);
// Prints the correct '/thumbnails/87991.png'
```

So in the `success()` of `$.ajax()`, I want to set that path as the value of a `src` attribute for an `<img>` on that page. For that, I want to generate a valid URL by passing it to the Laravel's *`url()`* helper. Like as follows.

```js
var thumbnailPhotoPathOnServer = "{{url(dataReturned)}}"; 
var thumbnailPhotoPathOnServer = "{{url('dataReturned')}}"; // I know it makes it a string but i still tried it out of desperation =(
var thumbnailPhotoPathOnServer = "@php echo url(dataReturned); @endphp";
```

I have tried all these statements but I keep getting

> Use of undefined constant dataReturned - assumed 'dataReturned' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

So that question is that what am I missing here and what should I do about it?

Comment: PHP can't read any JavaScript variables. PHP is executed first, on the server, and sends the output to the client - then the client runs the JavaScript, which is client-side.

Comment: You can send a request to the server through AJAX, where you send an argument which is the path, then return the `url($request->dataReturned);` - if you really need it (but I fail to see why when all you're doing is passing it through `url()` in PHP).

Comment: @Qirel Thank you, my bad! I am sorry. Now, this modifies my question. I need to use that dynamically generated path to generate URL, in order to display my picture in my `<img>`. There must be a way to do that?

Comment: If the JS variable `dataReturned` is generated clientside, can't you just display that directly? You don't need the full URL, you can do `<img src="/thumbnails/87991.png" />`.